Python __set__() descriptor behaviour
I have the following Python code snippet.
class LoggedAgeAccess:

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = obj._age
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj._age = value

class Person:

    age = LoggedAgeAccess()             # Descriptor instance

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name                # Regular instance attribute
        self.age = age                  # Calls __set__()

    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1                   # Calls both __get__() and __set__()

x = Person("ABC", 27)

In the constructor, the second assignment statement self.age = age triggers the __set__() method of the LoggedAgeAccess descriptor.
This is really confusing.
When the Person object is created, I am passing name and age values. Inside the constructor, I refer the passed value and create a instance specific variable self.age
whose value is assigned with the passed value (27). How this assignment statement refers the class level age variable and triggers a call to __set__()?

...handling assignment to that attribute is exactly what __set__ is supposed to do? Why are you surprised by __set__ doing its one job?

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

What specifically is confusing? What do you think should happen? And why do you think the actual behaviour should not happen?

The key is to recognize that self.age = age does not unconditionally create an instance attribute named age on the object self. Python first checks if self.__dict__['age'] already exists (it does not), if Person.age exists (it does) and if Person.age has a __set__ method (it does), and so invokes Person.age.__set__(self, age) instead of creating an instance attribute.
If self.__dict__['age'] does exist, the value is updated.
If Person.age was not already defined, then a new instance attribute named age is created. If Person.age does exists, but does not have a __set__ method, then a new instance attribute is also created, and that attribute shadows the class attribute with the same name.

Great, this is very crisp and provides the answer!

But one quick clarification.. While creating attributes, does it not follow the same order as attribute lookup? If it does, then age will be handled by a descriptor if it is available in the class. correct?

When the instance attribute does not exist, self.age can resolve to type(self).age, but self.age = age will never modify type(self).age, only define a new instance attribute.
